# persist session after closing browser

Tags: php

I have an ASP.NET Login App on my site and once logged in, I can navigate to the WordPress(PHP) side (still on the same domain) whilst maintaining the session. See my pastie link below for how this works.

However, the problem arises if I close my browser, I then lose the PHP 'session' despite keeping the ASP.NET session. So I'm 'logged out' on the PHP side but still 'logged in' on the .NET side.

-- Is there a way, using my existing code, to set a lifetime to the session/cookie, to avoid the session/cookie disappearing when I close my browser? --

I have pastie'd my current PHP code from my template's  here: http://pastie.org/private/ndcqgbog34uqld1etozda which checks and persists the session.

I did have a look at this example on PHP.net but got confused as to how to use it in my solution.

Many thanks for any pointers with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you should be using setcookie() with an expiry time (see here). You're only setting stuff in the session (copied from cookies, it looks like, but I'm not sure what their lifetime is).

Instead of this line:

```
$_SESSION[DOT_NET_SESSION][ $tuple['SessionName'] ] =
$tuple['SessionValue'];
```

Try this:

```
$cookie = array($tuple['SessionName'] => $tuple['SessionValue']);
setcookie(DOT_NET_SESSION, $cookie, time() + 60 * 60 * 24);
```

That should set a cookie for a day, I think.